# Access VBA Code Works - However, When Placed in SQL - Using the Same Table - It Doesn't

Tags: sql

This code works in Access VBA

```
LstSQL2 = "SELECT A.Assoc_ID, A.Full_Nm As [Agent Name], IIf(AssocName = Full_Nm,'Completed','Not Completed') AS Status " & _
              "FROM (SELECT Assoc_ID, Full_Nm FROM Tri_VassocView " & _
              "WHERE MgrName = '" & Me.LstSummary.Column(0) & "' " & _
              "GROUP BY Assoc_ID, Full_Nm)  AS A " & _
                "LEFT JOIN " & _
              "(SELECT AssocID, AssocName " & _
              "FROM Tri_OneonOne " & _
              "WHERE FORMAT(DateOfReview, 'MMMM')= ('" & Me.TxtMonth & "') " & _
              "AND FORMAT(DateOfReview, 'YYYY')= ('" & Me.TxtYear & "') " & _
              "GROUP BY AssocID, AssocName)  AS B " & _
              "ON A.Assoc_ID = B.AssocID " & _
              "GROUP BY A.Assoc_ID, A.Full_Nm, B.AssocID, B.AssocName " & _
              "ORDER BY IIf(AssocName = Full_Nm,'Completed','Not Completed');"
```

This code in SQL '14 produces all records as 'Not Completed' - For the Sup, Month & Year that are hard coded it should be 15/23 - Both queries pull from the same table.

```
SELECT A.Assoc_ID, A.Full_Nm As [Agent Name], CASE WHEN B.AssocName = A.Full_Nm THEN 'Completed' ELSE'Not Completed' END AS Status
FROM
    (SELECT Assoc_ID, Full_Nm
    FROM Tri.vassocView
    WHERE MgrName = 'Dolenz, Mickey'
    GROUP BY Assoc_ID, Full_Nm)  AS A
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT AssocID, AssocName
    FROM Tri.OneonOne
    WHERE DATENAME(M, DateOfReview)= ('February')
    AND DATENAME(Y, DateOfReview)= ('2020')
    GROUP BY AssocID, AssocName)  AS B
ON A.Assoc_ID = B.AssocID
GROUP BY A.Assoc_ID, A.Full_Nm, B.AssocID, B.AssocName
ORDER BY IIf(AssocName = Full_Nm,'Completed','Not Completed') DESC;
```

What am I not seeing??
[Edit] My apologies - I neglected to mention I believe the error is somewhere in the second (B) query as the first query pulls correct data...

Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.Assoc_ID, A.Full_Nm As [Agent Name], CASE WHEN B.AssocName = A.Full_Nm THEN 'Completed' ELSE 'Not Completed' END AS Status
FROM
    (SELECT Assoc_ID, Full_Nm
    FROM Tri.vassocView
    WHERE MgrName = 'Dolenz, Mickey'
    GROUP BY Assoc_ID, Full_Nm)  AS A
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT AssocID, AssocName
    FROM Tri.OneonOne
    WHERE DATENAME(M, DateOfReview)= ('February')
    AND DATENAME(YY, DateOfReview)= ('2020')
    GROUP BY AssocID, AssocName)  AS B
ON A.Assoc_ID = B.AssocID
GROUP BY A.Assoc_ID, A.Full_Nm, B.AssocID, B.AssocName
ORDER BY CASE WHEN B.AssocName = A.Full_Nm THEN 'Completed' ELSE 'Not Completed' END DESC
```